# AKS Ingress navigating to a URL path returns a 404, url changes to the index.html which is the correct route?

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

within my ingress file i have a path set up to navigate to my app, that routes to an application,

when i go to `myingresIp`/pss it redirects to `myingresip`/index.html, so it is almost like the routing is working its just not hitting my app.

I feel like the URL still needs to keep the /app prefix.

Can any one see what could be causing this problem or suggest a way of debugging this i am pretty new to AKS/kubernetes, or if there is some kind of logs that i can access to see what the underlying issue is?

Yaml:

[image: Service File]

[image]

[image]

The page i get then i navigate to `myingresIp`/pss is:
[image]

pod data:
[image]

Comment: Can you show give the output of the command `kubectl get pods`? You need to check the pods state.

Comment: @CharlesXu added.

Comment: It seems your ingress is not in the same namespace as your pod, doesn't it? Try to apply the deployment in the same namespace as your ingress.

Comment: I have changed it to be in the same namespace as a different namespace i already have, but still navigating to the route does not seem to fix this problem >.<

Comment: Can you share the chart? Maybe I can take a test for you.

Comment: What about your problem now? Do you solve it?

Comment: @CharlesXu sorry for the delay, do you have a way of me sending you the charts? Here is a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1r7afw03exd2og6/AAA7wNiJCy-IuO-6GY9FmGxSa?dl=0

Comment: Is that the real chart you use? The images cannot pull down.

Comment: yes the images are pulled from azure container registry

Comment: it turns out this was a routing issue, i adding in a $2, and some regex in the route path and it seems to work for now.

Comment: Well, if you solve it yourself, then you can add an answer to display it.